# Get Java to use tabs instead of spaces for indenting

Tags: java, xml, indentation

I'm creating an XML document. I got it to indent using 
`TransformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", new Integer(2));
Transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");`

Is it possible to get Java to use tabs instead of spaces for indenting? And how?

Comment: What difference would it make to have tabs instead of spaces?  Your editor likes tabs better?

Comment: transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4"); did the trick for me.  It's probably no guarantee, and in fact it seems to be highly dependent upon the version of java you are using.  Personally tabs vs. spaces means nothing when it's just meant to be a data file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in general. The XSLT specification does not allow for specifying WHAT whitespace to use when indenting.

It might, however, be a XSLT-processor specific item to configure.  Check the documentation for the one you are using.

If you REALLY want this, then you can use an afterburner XSLT-script on the output which does whatever you want to do on text()-nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, tabs are considered to be evil by a few. However, if you want to use `TransformFactory` and want to change the indenting behavior to use tabs instead of spaces, you need to provide your own implementation of `ContentHandler`.  Then pass your implementation of ContentHandler into a new `SAXResult` - pass that as the "result" to the `Transformer.transform(...)`. Lot of hoops to jump through.
Another consideration may be to use a smart XSLT over your output.

Answer (score 0):

I think not.

You can get the result and process it, replacing calling `str.replace("\n    ", "\n\t")` (or whatever number of spaces you want).

But I'd recommend against that - tabs aren't platform independent.

Comment: @Bozho, it may be dangerous to do a `str.replace` call as it might end up replacing some attribute values etc to tab from space; very undesirable isn't it?

Comment: That replaces only the first level of indentation.